# Swig-wx does not contain CMakeLists.txt file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

my current build of Groovy on ARM / Linaro 12.11 fails because swig-wx does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file. "git status" says it's "on branch groovy-devel". What's going on? Any idea how I can reconstruct this file?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Björn

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66483/swig-wx-does-not-contain-cmakelists.txt-file/) by [bjoerngiesler](https://answers.ros.org/users/4267/bjoerngiesler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

swig-wx is built using autotools not CMake. You need to do the standard ./configure && make && make install to compile it from source not add it to your catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0